# Spring Boot: switch between embedded and postgresql datasources by changing a flag

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, spring-data-jpa

I have created a spring boot application and have been using the H2 embedded database. Which is working fine.

However, I added the `application.properties` file and added the dependency to postgresql. This also works fine, but when I have to test my application I want to start it using the embedded DB. I don't see any other way of doing it except by removing the `application.properties` file, which is not a very neat way of doing it.

I was hoping that the flag `spring.datasource.initialization-mode=embedded` will make it load the embedded DB, but it is completely ignoring it.

Is there a way of achieving this by just turning a flag on and off?

I am using gradle as a build tool. If it's possible to achieve this via gradle, that would be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to what @Isank said, this might be useful in the cases when you want to run the application (not unit/integration tests, but maybe manually test it) using an in-memory database or just a different database.

You can define profiles, and for each profile you can have different application properties. Using the naming convention, let's say you have three environments (dev, prod, test), you define three different properties files:

```
application-dev.properties
application-prod.properties
application-test.properties
```

You need to put all these files in `src/main/resources/` so that they get picket up automatically. Alternatively, you need to tell spring-boot where the properties files are by passing the runtime argument `--spring.config.location`.

**Now, having all these files how do you tell spring-boot which one to use?**

If your properties files are named according to the convention `application-{profile}.properties`, then you do it by passing the `--spring.profiles.active={profile}` argument.

1. Running the `jar` file

```
java -jar spring-boo-app-name.jar --spring.profiles.active=prod 
//this will use the application-prod.properties file
```

2. Using the `bootRun` gradle task

```
bootRun {
    args '--spring.profiles.active=prod'
}
```

When you start your spring-boot app, you will see in the console the active profile.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any flag or any kind of toggling in this case. The `application.properties` that resides inside `src/main/resources` affect the application and the one inside `src/test/resources` affects the tests of that application.

Now, as you said you want to use an embedded DB for your tests all you need to use is `@DataJpaTest` on your test class.

`@DataJpaTest` provides some standard setup needed for testing the persistence layer:

- configuring H2, an in-memory database
- setting Hibernate, Spring Data, and the DataSource
- performing an @EntityScan
- turning on SQL logging

And, this is how your repository test will look like

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
public class SomeRepositoryIntegrationTest {}

    @Autowired
    private SomeRepository repository;

    // write test cases here
}
```

You can find a detailed tutorial on this topic [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testing)